# Cannot deploy Cloud Functions with Cloud Build saying "GOOGLE_MANIFEST_DANGLING_TAG: Manifest is still referenced by tag: latest"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, yaml, google-cloud-build, cicd

I'm trying to build a simple CI that goes

1. `When pushed to main branch on one of my Source Repo`
2. `Deploy Cloud Functions`

But after all process seems to succeed,
`Unable to delete previous cache image: DELETE・・・`
& the error in the title shows up and fails to deploy.

If I do this on console, it just comes through.
I've tried changing the role of Cloud Build service account from developer to owner but no luck.

Do I have to add some line in yaml to delete the cache? If so, where is the reference for that line?

Here is my yaml config;

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  args:
  - gcloud
  - functions
  - deploy
  - FUNCTION_NAME
  - --region=asia-northeast1
  - --memory=256MB
  - --trigger-topic=TOPIC_NAME
  - --retry
  - --runtime=python39
  - --entry-point=PYTHON_FUNC
  - --timeout=540s
  - --max-instances=1
  - --set-env-vars=[KEY=VALUE]
```

#### Update

I added
`- --remove-labels=[latest]`
in yaml but still no luck.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: No I tried deleting the cache in image registry first which didnt work.
Now just executing gcloud bat file for dployment at the same time commiting.

Answer (score 0):

From [gcloud cli docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) you must specify `--source` if updating a cloud function that was previously deployed from a git repository.

This is not mentioned i  thw cloud functions deployment docs but it did indeed fix the issue for me.

Comment: Ooooh, thought it's set on Cloud Build config level but have to write it in the code, too? Thank you very much! Will try this out.