# Is this another bug of gcloud CLI? Cannot remove a tag with digest reference,

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

This is related to my previous question.
[Cannot deploy Cloud Functions with Cloud Build saying "GOOGLE_MANIFEST_DANGLING_TAG: Manifest is still referenced by tag: latest"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70827532/cannot-deploy-cloud-functions-with-cloud-build-saying-google-manifest-dangling)

I've read that there is an issue in CLI
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr/issues/73

> **attempting to delete the manifest first before removing the tags**

So I'm trying to untag the cache image.
But
if I do

```
gcloud container images untag PATH/cashe@sha256:<digest>:latest
#PATH~DIGEST for sure has been copied from console
```

**there appears an error message** saying

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.untag) digest must be of the form "sha256:<digest>".
```

Looks to me it's trying to read strings next to the last :(colon) as digest and as tag name at the same time.

By the way this worked

```
gcloud container images untag PATH/cashe:latest --quiet
```

though there is a WARNING `: Successfully resolved tag to sha256, but it is recommended to use sha256 directly.`

Comment: Can you please let me know which gcloud version you are using? also did you tried with other version?

Answer (score 1):

Tags are a way to 'label' specific image (manifests) in a repository. The tag may only be used once per image in a repository.

[`gcloud container images untag`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/untag) requires `*.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_PATH:TAG`

You should **not** include the image's digest (== SHA256 of the manifest). Although including the digest does uniquely identify the image that's tagged, it's redundant; the repository is likely mapping tags (e.g. `latest`) to  image digests.

You should use:

```sh
gcloud container images untag ${PATH}/cashe:latest
```

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin
Thank you for your answer.

> The tag may only be used once per image in a repository.

So I learned after a while.
But considering what WARNING message is saying and the fact that I needed `--quiet`, I kept this up.
Sad thing is, even if I remove the tag or delete the cache image, the deployment still fails with the same error.